# How to customize placeholder looks in SwiftUI WidgetKit placeholder?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

With the way my code is set up, when my Widget is being displayed as a placeholder right before actual data comes in, it looks ugly because of the image placeholder being cut off by the Circle() clip path.

[image]

Here's the SwiftUI code (the first Image view is the view in question):

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 14, content: {
            Image(model.profileIcon).resizable()
                .padding(4)
                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                .background(Color("LightColor"))
                .clipShape(Circle())
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2, content: {
                Text(model.profileName)
                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                    .bold()
                Text("\(model.practiceToday) today")
                    .font(.system(size: 15)).fontWeight(.regular)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
            })
            Spacer()
        })
        
        Spacer()
        Divider()
        Spacer()
        
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10, content: {
            ForEach(0..<7) { i in
                SimpleProgressCircle(
                    progress: CGFloat(model.progress[i]),
                    day: model.weekdays[i],
                    today: i == 6)
            }
        })
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 2, bottom: 0, trailing: 2))
    }
    .padding(
        EdgeInsets(top: 17, leading: 15, bottom: 20, trailing: 15))
    .background(Color.foreground)
}
```

And the placeholder function in the main widget file:

```
func placeholder(in context: Context) -> WidgetContent {
    return WidgetContent(
        profileID: "",
        profileName: "----",
        profileIcon: "",
        weekdays: ["","","","","","",""],
        progress: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        practiceToday: "--"
    )
}
```

**Ideal outcome:** Placeholder just looks like a circle, without the inner rectangle

Comment: Did you solve this ? 
Have you played around with the `.redacted(reason: .placeholder)` and `.unredacted()`properties ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to declare :

```
@Environment(\.redactionReasons) private var reasons
```

And then to use it like this :

```
    if reasons.isEmpty { //Your regular view
      Image("fallback").resizable()
        .padding(4)
        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .clipShape(Circle())
    } else { //Example of placeholder
      Image("fallback").resizable()
        //.padding(4)
        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .clipShape(Circle())
    }
```

or this will do

```
Image("fallback").resizable()
    .padding(reasons.isEmpty ? 4: 0)
```